# Question that links to inappropriately named video

Tags: discussion

The recently asked question [Best power solution for my robot](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/best-power-solution-for-my-robot) includes a link for a video demonstrating the gait of the quadreped... all well and good. Unfortunately the title of the video leaves something to be desired.

What should be done in these sorts of cases? Delete the question, remove the link, or leave in place? I have left a comment for the OP, requesting that he change the title of the YouTube video, but it is out of SE's jurisdiction, so to speak. I have also flagged the question.

I don't want to sound puritanical, but the site is used by members of all ages.

#### Update

The title of the youtube video has now been changed, so this has, now, become a non-issue. However, what are the rules, should it happen again? I have read up on the "swearing" questions on Meta ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/whats-the-so-policy-for-swearing?), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites), and [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/how-much-what-kind-of-cursing-can-people-get-away-with-on-so?), etc., as well as these [behaviour guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)), but none seem to cover links to external inappropriate language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No site can control the content of links to external sites, and Stack exchange is no different.

If offensive content is on our site, the recommendation is to edit, flag or comment on it, depending on the severity. If offensive content is on another site, the best that we can do locally is remove the link (though without SE developer support it will still be in the history).

I think the solution used in this case was the best one though. A comment to bring it to the attention of the original poster, and for them to fix the problem at the remote site.